# Weather API - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

heres my problem I'm trying to write a script to get the weather for my location here is the code

```
import requests
url = ("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?key=hfvb4qmehh8g9p8krcbmj8ew&q=48.85,2.35&fx=no&format=json") 

r = requests.get(url)
forecast = r.json
print (forecast)["data"]["current_condition"]["temp_F"]
```

heres the error

```
<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Grant\Desktop\weather.py", line 6, in <module>
    print (forecast) ["data"]["current_condition"]["temp_F"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You probably shouldn't post your API key here.

Comment: honestly i dont care its a free site and i can just get a new one with the new api key request button

Answer (score 4):

```
print (forecast) ["data"]["current_condition"]["temp_F"]
```

indexes the result of the `print()` call. That's probably not what you want.

Try

```
print(forecast["data"]["current_condition"]["temp_F"])
```

instead.

Comment: changed the code to this import requests 
data =('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?key=hfvb4qmehh8g9p8krcbmj8ew&q=48.85,2.35&fx=no&format=json')
r = requests.get(data)
forecast = r.json
print (forecast)["data"]["current_condition"]["temp_F"] get this error <bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Grant\Desktop\google.py", line 5, in <module>
    print (forecast)["data"]["current_condition"]["temp_F"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable sorry about the retursn the dumb comment thing no return

Comment: @apples723 YOu just changed the whitespace, but not the essential thing. Change `()[][][]` to `([][][])`.

Comment: it says list needs to be integers